# Why does python's urljoin not work as expected?

Tags: python, url, urllib

With python 3.8 I want to join two parts of a URL into one. Here is an example:

```
domain = "https://some.domain.ch/myportal#/"
urllib.parse.urljoin(domain, "test1")
```

this gives the output

```
'https://some.domain.ch/test1'
```

but I expect the output

```
'https://some.domain.ch/myportal#/test1'
```

Asking just to understand.

As a workaround I will use

```
domain + "test1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
urllib.parse.urlparse(domain)
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='some.domain.ch', path='/myportal', params='', query='', fragment='/')
```

The problem is that you have a `#` in your path, which is incorrect per the specification [RFC-3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986.html) that `urllib.parse` follows.

See [§3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986.html#section-3) for a diagram of the parts of an URL :

```
         foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
         \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
          |           |            |            |        |
       scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
```

The `path` is defined in [§3.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986.html#section-3.3).
Yours is `/myportal`, which relates to the rules

```
path-absolute = "/" [ segment-nz *( "/" segment ) ]
...
segment-nz    = 1*pchar
```

whose `pchar` is defined in [§A](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986.html#appendix-A) :

```
   pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
...
   pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG

   unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
...
   sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
                 / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

The `#` can not be a `pchar` so the `path` stops there.

Either remove the `#` if it is not required :

```py
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.urljoin("https://some.domain.ch/myportal/", "test1")
'https://some.domain.ch/myportal/test1'
```

Or [percent-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) it :

```py
>>> urllib.parse.quote("#")
'%23'
>>> urllib.parse.urljoin("https://some.domain.ch/myportal%23/", "test1")
#                                                        ^^^
'https://some.domain.ch/myportal%23/test1'
```

Comment: To be precise, [`urllib.parse.urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit) was doing exactly what you expected, but your `domain` was incorrect. Also, your `domain` is actually not a "domain" but a "base_url".